# Browser game issue on Firefox Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, games

When I play browser games they usually don't load at all like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXhkm.png)

or they load up and their icons look weird like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pc0wM.png)
I have latest version of Firefox, all my drivers are updated and my 
[Flash drive is version 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83asF.png)

Please help, thanks and much love

Comment: Have you already tried "sudo apt install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash"? If not, how did you get the Flash plugin for Firefox?

Comment: Yes I have the pepperflash I also want to add, these games only work on chromium and never work on Firefox or Brave